# Solve for $X$ in a simple equation system.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I cannot really understand how to read this question, so please help me out here.

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & -6 & 4\\ 1 & 2 & 7\end{array} \right] = 4X + 5 \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 3 & 4 & 3\\ 8 & -4 & 8\end{array} \right]$$

First, how should i read this? Secondly how do I procede and solve for $X$, a full development would be very much appreciated!

Thank you kindly for you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two matrices are the same when all of their values are the same.
Lets call
$$X=\begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} \end{pmatrix}$$
So your equations are 
\begin{align*}
0&= 4 x_{11} +5 \cdot 3\\
-6&= 4 x_{12} + 5 \cdot 4\\
4&=4 x_{13} + 5 \cdot 3\\
1&= 4 x_{21} + 5\cdot 8\\
2&= 4x_{22} + 5 \cdot (-4)\\
7&= 4x_{23} + 5 \cdot 8
\end{align*}
Just solve those and write what $X$ is.

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent answer! I understand how this should be done now.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

You must see $X$ as a matrix of size $2\times 3$ and then you have
$$X=\frac{1}{4}\left(\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & -6 & 4\\ 1 & 2 & 7\end{array} \right]  - 5 \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 3 & 4 & 3\\ 8 & -4 & 8\end{array} \right]\right),$$
and you do the calculations on the components.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This was much easier than it looked (to me :))

Comment: You're welcome.